# Why there is no sign character in the syntax of constants?

Tags: c, syntax

Why doesn't the standard include a sign character in the syntax of constants?

It is mentioning only digits and sign character is **only present in exponents**.

Comment: _Which_ standard?

Comment: This is actually a rather insightful question. I don't understand the downvotes, and the votes to close.

Comment: @DYZ: Given that the question is flagged as C, there seems to be a limited number of standards to choose from, and I doubt any of them differ in this regard.

Comment: Both answers are correct; `-1` is not a constant, it's an expression consisting of a unary `-` operator applied to the constant `1`. This can cause issues. For example, suppose `int` has a range of `-32768` .. `+32767`. Then the expression `-32768` is *not* of type `int`. The constant `32768` is of type `long`, and the unary `-` doesn't change that type.

Comment: @MDXF: What do you find unclear about it? I can't say I stumbled on anything myself when reading it.

Comment: @Dolda2000 What exactly is a *sign character*?

Comment: @MDXF: How could that possibly mean anything but the `+` or `-` preceding a numeric literal?

Comment: @Dolda2000 Well, yeah, but why would unary operations be in the *syntax of constants?*

Comment: @MDXF: A sign character is `-` or `+`.

Comment: @MDXF: That's the question, kind of. Only vice versa.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Ah, and now the accepted answer. I see. Thanks for clarifying. Still a bit unclear, but not enough to close, I guess...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard does not bother with the sign in front of numeric literals because it would be redundant.

The syntax already captures the sign as part of unary plus `+` and unary minus `-` operators. When you write

```
int a = -4;
```

the syntax of the right-hand side could be adequately described as a unary minus `-` expression with the operand of `4`. This is the approach that the standard takes.

Comment: Just to be clear, is that sufficient to handle stuff like `INT_MIN` in a two's complement system where the absolute value of `INT_MIN` is not representable as an `int`? I'm not a language lawyer on stuff like this; I'd assume that separating the two elements would cause issues when the operand (without sign) isn't legal on its own.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: The literals themselves don't need to fit within the range of an `int`. You can view them as arbitrary-precision integers that are "casted" to the datatype they're actually used as.

Comment: @Dolda2000: No, each literal (the C standard calls them "constants", but it's the same idea) has a specific type. The rules are in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.4.1.1. The type of an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is the first of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` in which its value will fit.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: That can be an issue. If `INT_MIN` is -32768, then the expression `-32768` is of type `long`, not of type `int`. You might see `INT_MIN` defined in `<limits.h>` as something like `(-32767-1)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oh, really? I was not aware of that; thanks for the correction. I really should actually read the standard one of these days.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Wouldn't 5.2.4.2.1p1 ("_... the following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer promotions ..._") be a better fit?

Answer (score 5):

If `-` were a part of the constant `-2` then `4-2` would be a syntax error (since a token is always the longest possible sequence of characters). Also, the  semantics of `-2147483648` and `- 2147483648` would be different (the first one would be an `int` and the second one a `long`, assuming `int` is 32 bits and `long` is longer). Both of those things would be confusing.

If the `-` is always an operator, the semantics of `-2147483648` are sometimes a little unexpected, but the more common `x-1` works as expected. So that's how most programming languages, including C, work.

Comment: As is `a++++b` (actually both are not syntax errors). Adding spaces makes both valid expressions: `a++ + ++b` and `4 - 2`. That would not be a valid reason. The simple answer is: there is no need, as the `-` operator is required anyway for non-constants.

Comment: @Olaf: yes, but most languages do not *require* you to put a space in `4-2`, and there is quite a lot of code out there in many languages which shows that not all programmers expect to do that. Language designers tend to design for their users. (And themselves: K&R were not big consumers of whitespace.)

Comment: Not needing spaces is just a side-effect of not having negative integer constants. The major reason is that is simplifies both the scanner and the parser for not implementing the same semantice twice (negation for constants and for variables).